# How can I edit kaazing's server code?

Tags: websocket

I'm using [Kaazing Websocket Gateway](http://www.kaazing.com/products/kaazing-websocket-gateway) and I can run the demos - everything is working.
But I want to change the server code (the code that handles the websockets sent to the server and responds). How can I do that?

Comment: I came here to ask people who know this...

Comment: Though I have no idea what KWG is, I think what NLV means is that only Kaazing can change that code, so you'll have to contact their support.

Comment: No, NLV means I should ask them for help (it's not his business).
BTW: I've asked them (waiting for respond), but NLV is still wrong...

Answer (score 3):

Zippo,
Would you mind telling me how you have contacted Kaazing Support. I can find no voicemail, forum entry or record of a call. I'd like to make sure we didn't miss anything.

It sounds like you would like to change the Gateway code? If that is so, the answer is that we offer a developer's version of the Gateway with unlimited connections. We don't currently offer a an open source version.
If I have misunderstood your question please contact Kaazing Global Support with your question so we can help you out. Call our switch board at 1-877-KAAZING (1-877-522-9464) and ask for "Technical Support".

Regards

Jan Carlin

Director Kaazing Global Support